# Chained API Call : Membership.contact_id EntityTags

Tags: civimember, api, tags

I am looking to get a list of all contacts with active memberships, and their respective tags.  I went about this by starting from an api call to give me all current memberships owned by a company.

```
CRM.api3('Membership', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": ["contact_id.tag","contact_id.id"],
  "status_id": "Current",
  "contact_id.contact_type": "Organization"
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

Running the above only gets me the default returns vals of the contact_id and id of the membership. It does not return the tags.

When I run this by itself:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('EntityTag', 'getsingle', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => 137402,
));
```

I get what I want, the tag ids for the contact.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would be using the $value.contact_id var but I can't get it to work that way.

membership->tags (via contact_id)

What I did get working was inserting a 3rd link in the api call chain.

membership->contact->tags

```
CRM.api3('Membership', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "status_id": "Current",
  "options": {"limit":0},
  "contact_id.contact_type": "Organization",
  "api.Contact.get": {"api.EntityTag.get":{}}
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: A little late but just perused this... might be obvious to others but in case it's helpful... to get $value.contact_id working I had to escape the $. So my chained call looked like 'api.Contact.get' => array('id' => "\$value.contact_id", etc

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to do chained api call, like you did with :

```
"api.Contact.get": { "sequential": 1, "api.EntityTag.get":{}}
```

Second, you can filter the result of your chained call by doing so :

```
"$value.api.Contact.get.contact_type": "Organization"
```

Third, to get the result of your chained api call, you need to do something like :

```
tags = result['values'][0]['api.Contact.get']['values'][0]['api.EntityTag.get']['values'];
```

If you want something a little less complex, you can use `getsingle` or `getvalue` instead of get. This way, you won't have to loop on `values`

So the final result should look like :

```
CRM.api3('Membership', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "api.Contact.getsingle": {
    "api.EntityTag.get" : {}
  }
  "status_id": "Current",
  "$value.api.Contact.getsingle.contact_type": "Organization"  // instead of contact_id.contact_type
}).done(function(result) {
  // replace by a loop on membership...
  tags = result['values'][0]['api.Contact.getsingle']['api.EntityTag.get']['values'];
});
```